# kotlin data class + bean validation jsr 303

Tags: jpa, bean-validation, kotlin, spring-data-rest, data-class

I'm trying to get Kotlin working with jsr 303 validation on a spring-data-rest project.

Given the following data class declarartion :

```
@Entity data class User(
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Size(min=5, max=15)
    val name: String
)
```

The @Size annotation has no effect here, making me able to save a user with a name of 1 character.
It works well when executing the very same example but in a Java class instead of Kotlin.

This makes me think of a Kotlin problem.

Thanks in advance for you help !

Comment: what should be the target of the annotation? Constructor parameter or the field?

Comment: Many thanks for the question. I desperately looking what is wrong !

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You need to use [Annotation use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) since the default for a property declared in the constructor is to target the annotation on the constructor **parameter** instead of the **getter** (which will be seen by JavaBeans compliant hosts) when there are multiple options available.  Also using a `data` class might be inappropriate here (*see note at end*).

```
@Entity data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @get:Size(min=5, max=15) // added annotation use-site target here
    val name: String
)
```

The `property` target from the Kotlin docs may look tempting, but it can only be seen from Kotlin and not Java.  Usually `get` does the trick, and it is not needed on the bean `set`.

The docs describe the process as:

> If you don’t specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according to the @Target annotation of the annotation being used. If there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the following list is used:
>
> - param
> - property
> - field

And the `@Size` annotation is:

```
@Target(value={METHOD,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR,PARAMETER})
```

Therefore since `PARAMETER` is a valid target, and multiple targets are available (parameter, field, method [get/set]) it choses `PARAMETER` which is not what you want.  Therefore for a JavaBean host to see the property it will look for the getter (properties are defined by the getter/setter and not the backing field).

In one of the [Java samples](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec), it shows:

```java
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String description;

    // ...

    @NotEmpty(groups={FirstLevelCheck.class, Default.class})
    @Size(max=30)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Which matches our usage of having it on the getter.  If it were to be on the field like some of the validation annotations show, see the `field` use-site target.  Or if the field must also be publicly accessible, see the [@JvmField annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields) in Kotlin.

***NOTE:*** *As mentioned in notes from others, you should likely consider NOT using a `data` class for entities if they use an auto-generated ID since it will not exist for new objects the same as for retrieved objects; and a `data` class will generate `equals` and `hashCode` to include all fields including the ones it should not.  You can read guidance about this from the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html).*

Comment: You rock ! Thanks !

It is also possible to use the `@get:Size(min=5, max=15)` annotation.

Comment: Although it's correct answer it's worth to note that you should not use `data class` for entity anyway. The reason is - it will generate `equals` and `hashCode` methods using all properties, including `id`, which is not desired behavior for JPA entity. See here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html

Comment: thanks @waste, I made an edit to add the note directly in the answer.

Comment: "If there are explicit implementations of equals(), hashCode() or toString() in the data class body or final implementations in a superclass, then these functions are not generated, and the existing implementations are used"   - kotlin docs

Comment: Oh god, Thank you soooooo much for this answer.I've lost a day about it figuring out why my annotation wasn't taking into consideration...

Answer (score 20):

**Use the `@get` or `@field` targets** for [validation annotations](https://hibernate.org/validator). Annotations with the target `@param`(first default) and `@property` are not supported.

e.g:

From `@NotEmpty` To `@field:NotEmpty`

```
data class Student(
    @field:NotEmpty @field:Size(min= 2, message = "Invalid field") var name: String? = ""
)
```

GL

- [Jayson Minard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35853200/5279996)
- [Annotation use site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)