# Kotlin spring boot validation does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, kotlin

When i do a POST request to /register with user with null email, i expect it to say something "hey, you have null in email field", but it throws NPE on saving step because of `user.email!!` statement.
When i send json with wrong email like this:

```
{
  "email": "wrongEmailAddress",
  "username": "username",
  "phoneNumber": "+7 909 909 9009",
  "password": "234adfg24",
  "role": "USER"
}
```

it perfectly passes through this constraint annotation:

```
@Email
@Pattern(regexp = ".+@.+\\..+", message = "Please provide a valid email address")
@Target(
        AnnotationTarget.FIELD,
        AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
        AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [])
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class ValidEmail(
        val message: String = "Please provide a valid email address",
        val groups: Array<KClass<out Any>> = [],
        val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)
```

[request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPVq8.png)

Why does not validation work?

Controller class:

```
@RestController
class UserController(
        @Autowired val userService: UserService) {

    @PostMapping(
            path=["/register"],
            consumes=["application/json"],
            produces=["application/json"])
    fun registerNewUser(
            @Valid @RequestBody user: User): UserDTO {
        user.encryptPassword()
        userService.registerNewUser(user)
        return UserDTO(user)
    }
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
class User(
        @get:NotNull @field:ValidEmail @Column(unique = true)
        var email: String? = null,
        @get:NotNull @Column(unique = true)
        var username: String? = null,
        @get:NotNull @field:ValidPhoneNumber @Column(unique = true)
        var phoneNumber: String? = null,
        @get:NotNull @field:ValidPassword
        var password: String? = null,
        @get:NotNull
        var role: Role? = null,

        var address: String? = null
) : BaseEntity()
{
    fun encryptPassword() {
        password = BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password)
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
open class BaseEntity(
        @Id @NotNull @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
        @GenericGenerator(name="UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
        open val id: UUID? = null)
```

What i tried. I tried to change between @ValidEmail, @get:ValidEmail, @field:ValidEmail ( [kotlin data class + bean validation jsr 303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847763/kotlin-data-class-bean-validation-jsr-303) , https://stackoverrun.com/ru/q/9883168 and other sources), tried to rewrite everything in java. Nothing works. PhoneNumberValidator passes all unit tests, but the constraint @ValidPhoneNumber does not work too. Not even one constraint work.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Use @Pattern directly on field

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks it does not fix the problem with any other constraint.

Answer (score 4):

Mark your restcontroller with @Validated.

Comment: it does not work. this annotation is used to allow validating request parameters and path variables ( https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/ ) i have another java project with bean validation where everything works properly without @Validated

Comment: did you try to add rhe @Valid annotation on the property?

Comment: if you mean validation on request params and path vars like i mentioned, answer is no, but even @NotNull annotation on class property does not work

Comment: What Spring boot version are you using?

Comment: 2.3.2.RELEASE.
Problem solved after i recreated project with gradle and everythink works now, used maven before. btw was it my fault or maven really such a bad thing?

Comment: Perhaps you needed to do a mvn clean install. Also, I was going to say you needed to include spring-boot-starter-validation since in the newest versions this is not automatically packaged with spring boot anymore.

Comment: i did clean and then install didnt work anymore, it was saying "symbol not found", before it worked ok, dont wanna deal with maven anymore